# Fraction inside \xrightarrow is giving error

Tags: arrows, fractions, mathtools

If I write:

```
    $\xrightarrow{\makebox[4cm]{\frac{m}{n}}}$
```

I'm getting error:

```
    Missing $ inserted \end{frame}
    Extra}, or forgotten $ \end{frame}
```

But replacing    \frac{m}{n} with just 1 (for checking)  i.e.

```
    $\xrightarrow{\makebox[4cm]{1}}$
```

is working as expected.
Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Try `$\frac{m}{n}$`. `\makebox` expects text arguments so you need to go back into math mode.  Fur future reference, please post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up/reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why

```
$\xrightarrow{\makebox[4cm]{\frac{m}{n}}}$
```

throws an error message whereas

```
$\xrightarrow{\makebox[4cm]{1}}$
```

does not is that the contents of the mandatory argument of `\makebox` are evaluated in text mode by default. `1` is a valid text-mode object, whereas `\frac` is not.

To avoid getting the error message, you need to write

```
$\xrightarrow{\makebox[4cm]{$\frac{m}{n}$}}$
```

---

*Addendum*: As pointed out by @daleif (the maintainer of the `mathtools` package) in a comment, you could also solve the problem by loading the `mathtools` package and issuing the instruction

```
$\xrightarrow{\makemathbox[4cm]{\frac{m}{n}}}$
```

As the macro's name suggests, the contents of the argument of `\makemathbox` are treated as math-mode items.

Comment: Or use mathtools, it has a mathmakebox

Comment: @daleif - excellent suggestion! :-) I've edited my answer and provided an addendum to give the suggestion the prominence it deserves.